# Dropwizard-swagger with Dropwizard 1.3

Tags: glassfish, swagger, dropwizard

I am using the dropwizard-swagger dependency with Dropwizard 1.3 as follows

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.smoketurner</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-swagger</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0-1</version>
        </dependency>
```

From the docs , it looks like this is the only compatible version . However I run into an issue

```
ClassNotFoundException: org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.ClassEventListener
```

From some research it looks like this is coming from a glassfish dependency, I dont seem to find anything that brings in this dependency. Wat have I missed?

Comment: Please share the full list of dependencies in the POM.

Answer (score 0):

After digging into the source code of: dropwizard-swagger I found that in versions hihger than 1.1.0-1 they introduced BeanConfig. BeanConfig scanns all classes (not only the ones you set as resource packages) and tries to create class objects for them.

The "problem" is that there are plenty of classes in the resulting shaded jar that are using import statements of classes that are not provided/used by your (or alt least mine) dropwizard application.

Simple solution: roll back to dropwizard-swagger version 1.1.0-1
drawback: you are limited to an older swagger version

hard solution: figure out which dependencies are pulling in classes that are using imports to the classes that are failing during dropwisard app start

NOTE!
I'm using dropwizard-bom and I don't have any strange dependencies

Answer (score 0):

For me excluding `org.reflections` solved the issue...

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.smoketurner</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-swagger</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5-3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
                <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used swagger for documentation and this works for me..

````
            <groupId>com.smoketurner</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-swagger</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.12-1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>```
````

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the [swagger-core](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations) project. I initially planned on using dropwizard-swagger in my project before discovering that swagger-core supports newer versions of OpenAPI and integrates into my dropwizard project without dependency issues.